# cursors and update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I'm getting an error message when I'm trying to execute this code in SQL Server 2005:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'close'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near 'dbname'.

What is wrong with my code?

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(max), @stat nvarchar(max)   

set @stat = N'update DBNAME.dbo.Ad 
set Label = ''Special Ad'' where Label =''AdXXXX'''

DECLARE dbname CURSOR FOR select name from sys.databases where name like '%config%'

open dbname   
begin try
    while 1=1 
    begin
      fetch next from dbname into @name
      set @stat=REPLACE(@stat,'DBNAME',@name)
      exec sp_executesql @stat
    end  
end try

close dbname   
deallocate dbname
```

Comment: I don't use `TRY` that much in TSQL, but shouldn't there be a `CATCH` in there, somewhere?

Comment: just out of curiosity, how do you intend to stop that `while`?

Comment: @CyberDude -- I assume he'll fetch past the end of the cursor and get a runtime error.

Comment: `FETCH` doesn't cause any error when passing "outside" the result set, it keeps on returning empty sets

Answer (score 2):

A `TRY` block must be immediately followed by a `CATCH` block:

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- some statements here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- other statements here
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following [sql cursor](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/cursor.aspx) script

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(max), @stat nvarchar(max)

DECLARE dbname CURSOR FOR select name from sys.databases --where name like '%config%'  
open dbname    

FETCH NEXT FROM dbname INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    set @stat = N'update DBNAME.dbo.Ad  set Label = ''Special Ad'' where Label =''AdXXXX'''  
    set @stat=REPLACE(@stat,'DBNAME',@name)       
    exec sp_executesql @stat     

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbname INTO @name   
END

close dbname    
deallocate dbname
```

Note that the set @stat declaration statement is moved into the cursor
Because after the first replace the original @stat changes and you'll not be able to alter it again

Answer (score 0):

you have a `TRY` block without a `CATCH` block:

```
...
open dbname   
begin try
  while 1=1 begin
      fetch next from dbname into @name
      set @stat=REPLACE(@stat,'DBNAME',@name)
      exec sp_executesql @stat

  end  
end try
begin catch
    <..some error handling code>
end catch
...
```

See the documentation on [`TRY...CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)